# Redirect user to the second last page in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a model class `Event` which has the following actions in question: `view` and `delete`.

The deletion can only happen from the `view` action. Getting to the view action is possible from two places that are:

```
events/dashboard
```

and

```
calendar/view_calendar
```

the latter takes three parameters: `user_id`, `month` and `year` so that would for example be

`calendar/view_calendar/120/5/2014`

So depending on which action user got to for example `events/view/1400`, he has to be redirected accordingly.

The referer does not work as it redirects to the `events/view` with the `id` of event which has already been deleted.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: you can apply fetch sql first then delete the record from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a second Parameter to the view, like

```
events/view/1400/0
```

for dashboard

and

```
events/view/1400/1
```

for view_calendar

and pass these params to your delete action, like

```
events/delete/1400/1
```

In your delete function you can you use the usual redirect:

```
if($secondParam == 1) {
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view_calendar'));
} else {
    if($secondParam == 0) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save somewhere the information about the referrer when you land in `events/view` and the pass it to `events/delete`.

You can use a named parameter or a query string so your link to the delete action becomes appear something like

```
events/delete/1400/referrer:dashboard
```

or

```
events/delete/1400/referrer:view_calendar
```

or

```
events/delete/1400/?referrer=dashboard
```